# Rake assets precompile error because of not in css file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to precompile the assets in production but I'm getting an error. I googled it for hours but could not find the answer. Please see the code and error below:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...-menu > li:not(": expected ")", was "":.treeview") >..."
```

***.css

```
.sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .sidebar-menu > li:not(.treeview) > a > span {
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

Its raising error near not. Can anyone help me out. Its just a simple syntax change.

Answer (score 0):

Try only using "**@Import**" in your aplication stylesheet, some scss assets break when you use "require"

why? because require is for "**.css**", @import is for "**.scss**" (sass)

if you are importing assets from a gem, look for that gem documentation on how to replace require with import

Comment: its not about breaking. have to change some syntax